# Wrap a long caption in a <figure> element

Tags: css, bulma

I'd like to display an image on the right side of a text with a caption. The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>figure example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <figure class="is-pulled-right">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png"
        width="128" height="128" alt="Example">
        <figcaption>
          <small>Long Text. Longer than the image is wide. Lorem ipsum dolor
          sit amet.</small>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result:

[image: Screenshot of the webpage]

Because the text of the caption is long the image gets a lot of real estate. How can I wrap the text of the caption so that is doesn't take more width than the image? I want the image to be on the right side of the text.

BTW: Is `<figure class="is-pulled-right">` the right way of tackling this problem? `columns` work but obviously don't let the text flow around the `<figure>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I have added css for this.

```css
.is-pulled-right {      
  margin-left: 4%;
  width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>figure example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <figure class="is-pulled-right">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png"
        width="128" height="128" alt="Example">
        <figcaption>
          <small>Long Text. Longer than the image is wide. Lorem ipsum dolor
          sit amet.</small>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum. 
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't override native css classes. Create a new class instead!